# Guard unexpected tIdentifier error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, guard

I'm new to coding and hope that I followed all of the rules accordingly to post this question.

I'm going through a Ruby on Rails introduction and in one of my examples I'm getting the following 'Unexpect tIDENTIFIER' message when GUARD runs and I can't seem to figure out why.

```
ERROR["test_should_get_about", StaticPagesControllerTest, 0.012288]
test_should_get_about#StaticPagesControllerTest (0.01s)
SyntaxError:         SyntaxError: /Users/NateFeder/_projectbox/rails-tutorial/sample_app/app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb:12: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
    About |Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App
                  ^
ERROR["test_should_get_home", StaticPagesControllerTest, 0.004128]
test_should_get_home#StaticPagesControllerTest (0.00s)
SyntaxError:         SyntaxError: /Users/NateFeder/_projectbox/rails-tutorial/sample_app/app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb:12: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
    About |Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App

ERROR["test_should_get_help", StaticPagesControllerTest, 0.008452]
test_should_get_help#StaticPagesControllerTest (0.01s)
SyntaxError:         SyntaxError: /Users/NateFeder/_projectbox/rails-tutorial/sample_app/app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb:12: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
    About |Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App
```

My StaticPagesControllerTest is below:

```
require 'test_helper'

class StaticPagesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

test "should get home" do
get :home
assert_response :success
assert_select "title", 'Home | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App'
end

 test "should get help" do
get :help
assert_response :success
assert_select "title", 'Help | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App'

end

test "should get about" do
get :about
assert_response :success
assert_select 'title", "About | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App'

end

end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your error is that you're using inconsistent single vs double quotes:

```
test "should get about" do
get :about
assert_response :success
assert_select 'title", "About | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App'
# ------------^ here

end
```

This is more subjective, but to avoid this kind of error it's probably a good idea to pick one (single or double) and stick to it unless you have to use something else (ie to do `#{}` string interpolation)

Comment: Thanks glittershark. I had seen that after I posted the question and fixed it. Still, I continued to get the error after.

Answer (score 0):

After going back through the folders I realized I had an extra layout_file. I deleted the extra file and the errors went away. Woot!

Lesson learned.